# Combine LIKE within an IN statement in SQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hey guys I have a query which currently takes a list of keywords from a form and returns the top 5 matching associated statements. These are in two different tables (`Keyword` & `Problem`). The problem Im having is that if someone searches for TURNS a result is returned but if you search for TURN there are no results. I know this seems simple but the query I'm working with is a little less so. This is the query I'm working with:

```
SELECT p.*, pc.wordCount, pc.commonCount    
FROM Problem p INNER JOIN (
SELECT p.Problem_Identity, COUNT(k.Keyword_Identity) AS "wordCount",
SUM(k.Keyword_Common) as "commonCount"
FROM( SELECT * FROM Keyword ) k
INNER JOIN KeywordsInProblem kip ON (k.Keyword_Identity = kip.Keyword_Identity)
INNER JOIN Problem p ON (p.Problem_Identity = kip.Problem_Identity)
WHERE UCASE(k.Keyword_Word) IN(\''. strtoupper(implode("', '", $keyArr)) .'\')
GROUP BY p.Problem_Identity) pc
ON (p.Problem_Identity = pc.Problem_Identity) where pc.commonCount > 0
ORDER BY pc.wordCount DESC, pc.commonCount DESC LIMIT 5
```

PS: the  `$keyArr` variable is one which explodes the form input statement in order to sanitize it before using it in the database.

Comment: `a like b or a like c or a like d ...`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$likeCondition = "";
foreach($keyArr as $key)
{
    $likeCondition .= (strlen(trim($likeCondition)))?
           " OR UCASE(k.Keyword_Word) LIKE '%".strtoupper($key)."%' ":
           " WHERE UCASE(k.Keyword_Word) LIKE '%".strtoupper($key)."%' ";
}

$sql = "SELECT 
    p.*, 
    pc.wordCount, 
    pc.commonCount    
FROM 
    Problem p 
        INNER JOIN (
            SELECT 
                p.Problem_Identity, 
                COUNT(k.Keyword_Identity) AS wordCount,
                SUM(k.Keyword_Common) AS commonCount
            FROM(
                SELECT * FROM Keyword) k
                    INNER JOIN 
                        KeywordsInProblem kip 
                    ON 
                        (k.Keyword_Identity = kip.Keyword_Identity)
                    INNER JOIN 
                        Problem p 
                    ON 
                        (p.Problem_Identity = kip.Problem_Identity)
                ".$likeCondition."
        GROUP BY p.Problem_Identity) pc
        ON 
            (p.Problem_Identity = pc.Problem_Identity) 
        WHERE 
            pc.commonCount > 0
ORDER BY pc.wordCount DESC, pc.commonCount DESC LIMIT 5";
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to iterate through $keyArr and concat this each iteration

```
OR UCASE(k.Keyword_Word) like \''.$keyArr[i] .'% \'
```

Having all this restrictions wrapped by ()

Comment: So I would need to count $keyArr then iterate that statement for each instance?

Comment: Yes. You can't do a like inside an IN in sql, so you have to do this workaround